# Single access_token for multiple copy of identity server

Tags: identityserver4, identityserver3

We have app that uses identity server. We deployed it to cluster A. We also deployed the same app to cluster B.

Is it possible to login to app on cluster A and be able to entry to cluster B without second login ?

Both app A and B have Identity server inside it and every uses external authentication with Microsoft identity provider, therefore my question was if there is copy of the entire app including identity server, is it possible to login into app A and be able to user app B with the same token from app A ?

I just run one identity server locally and second on local docker and I have webapi connected to my local identity server instance, I could login, when I change ports to use identity sever on docker I get unauthorized. So something must be change to get this working.

I know already that there will be different issuer depends identity server on cluster A or B.

At the end I am trying to do like this: user login to cluster A, then want to go to cluster B, we remove his token, and when he goes to cluster B I thought that using microsoft cookie he will be logged in authomatically to cluster B. But is not, the cookie is different if he got token from cluster A from this one if he got it from cluster B. So every time user switch cluster he must log in again. any help about that ?

Comment: If cluster A and B have different URLs from the point of view of the user then no. However since you're using Microsoft as your ultimate auth provider then the chances are that the user may not have to interactively sign in but if you go from A -> B then B will still need to perform a sign in redirect to Identity B as no authentication cookie will be present for client A or Identity A.

Comment: @mackie at the end I am trying to do like this: user login to cluster A, then want to go to cluster B, we remove his token, and when he goes to cluster B I thought that using microsoft cookie he will be logedin authomaticly to cluster B. But is not , the cookie is different if he got token from cluster A from this one if he got it from cluster B. So every time user switch cluster he must log in again. any help about that ?

Comment: So you’re saying when the user logs into Identity A using Microsoft and then tries to go to Identity B, he has to log in with a Microsoft again? That shouldn’t be the case unless you’re deleting the Microsoft cookies or forcing the login page from the Identity Servers request to Microsoft